# How to get custom data from WooCommerce checkout form for delivery cost calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I have an woocommerce checkout custom form, but i wanna get the geolocalization inputs for delivery cost calculation. I can't do it.

The code is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge($cart) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $url=$api_url."wp/orders/calculo/envio";
    $data =[
        "longitude_customer" => 0, // I HAVE THIS VALUE ON MY CHEKOUT FORM
        "latitude_customer" => 0, // I HAVE THIS VALUE ON MY CHEKOUT FORM
        "longitude_origin" => 0, // I HAVE THIS VALUE ON MY CHEKOUT FORM
        "latitude_origin" =>0 // I HAVE THIS VALUE ON MY CHEKOUT FORM
    ];
    $response = httpPost($url, $data);
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Delivery', $response['cost'], true, '' );
}

function httpPost($url, $data) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: what is the error??

Comment: i can't get the geolocalization data from my chekout form

Comment: What error do you see exactly, and what have you tried already?

Comment: I have geo data on my form.

Comment: but i can't acces to them on my cart

Comment: basically, you are saying that your $data variable is receiving no data ?

Comment: I can't get order fields, I can't get checkout fields , i only can get cart fileds but  in the cart fields i don't have my fileds of location,

Comment: You need to use Ajax… and a WC Session variable… no other ways to make it work.